# Transaction Failing due to invalid funds provided

Tags: ether, ethers.js, etherscan, goerli

I am trying to call a transaction and have it set like the image below, but for some reason the transaction is failing with "Invalid funds provided". I am not too sure what is going on. I provided the etherscan transaction result and the way that I am calling my function below. I think the problem here is how much I am sending within the transaction? [image: Etherscan Transaction response][1]]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the problem, the error message was a custom one from the smart contract.